# Laurent series of $\frac{1}{\cos{\frac{1}{z}}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider
$$
f(z) =\frac{1}{\cos{\frac{1}{z}}}.
$$
Clearly $0$ is not an isolated singularity. However,  We have
$$ \begin{align}
 f(z)& = \frac{1}{\cos (\frac{1}{z})} = \frac{1}{1 -  \frac{1}{2z^{2}} +  \frac{1}{24z^{4}}  + O(z^{-6})} \\ 
  &  =1 + (\frac{1}{2z^{2}} -  \frac{1}{24z^{4}} + O(z^{-6})) + (\frac{1}{2z^{2}} -  \frac{1}{24z^{4}} - + O(z^{-6}))^{2} +  \dots  \\
  &  = 1 + \frac{1}{2z^{2}} +  \frac{5}{24z^4} +  O\left(\frac{1}{z^5} \right)
  \end{align}$$

Which seems to be verified by Wolfram alpha [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=laurent%20series%20of%201%2F%28cos%281%2Fz%29%29). I think that what is going wrong here is that the geometric series doesn't necessarily converge and this is why we get this false-looking expression but I could be wrong.

Could someone explain what is going on here? In other words, is this result true and if so, does this mean we can have Laurent series about a non-isolated singularity? If not where is the mistake?

Comment: @Gary I think it is a non-isolated?

Comment: Is there a neighborhood of infinity where $f$ is analytic?

Comment: Hi, I see that there is one, however, here I am expanding about $0$. Is what you are saying that this expansion is valid for a sufficiently large anulus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have not been clear what you actually mean by "$\mathcal{O}$". "$\mathcal{O}(1/z)$" as $z$ tends to *what*?

Given: $$\sec s=1+\frac{1}{2}s^2+\frac{5}{24}s^4+\mathcal{O}(s^6),\,\,\,s\to0$$

You know that: $$f(z)=1+\frac{1}{2}z^{-2}+\frac{5}{24}z^{-4}+\mathcal{O}(z^{-6}),\,\,s=\frac{1}{z}\to0$$*That is*, as $z\to\infty$. The expansion is not correct if you interpret the $\mathcal{O}$'s as "as $z\to0$".

This Laurent expansion at $\infty$ is perfectly fine, and does not imply $0$ is an isolated singularity for $f$.